# Rspec before method

Tags: rspec

If a spec file contains this before the it() example groups, what does it mean?

```
context "when almost full (with one element less than capacity)" do
  before(:each) do
    @stack = Stack.new
    (1..9).each { |n| @stack.push n }
  end
end

context "when full" do
  before(:each) do
    @stack = Stack.new
    (1..10).each { |n| @stack.push n }
  end
end
```

Which one will be the one that is executed before?

I don't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`before(:each)` will get run prior to running any specs that follow. So for example, in your spec for a full stack, any specifications will have a full stack set up prior being executed. You don't have any `It` methods, so that does not really occur at present however.

It may be worth noting there is `before(:all)` which will be run *once*, prior all specs for that context. Whereas `before(:each)` gets run prior to each spec.

Comment: but i have two different before(:each) in the example. i wonder which one will be executed if i have had some it() blocks.

Comment: The `before(:each)` method is run for all examples within the context where it is defined. The way your spec is written the two `before(:each)` methods are in separate contexts, so they will both run, but not for the same examples.

Comment: Zetetic beat me to my reply, but he's spot on. As the contexts are not nested, each set up will be run individually, and not interfere with each other.